# Get product id in Magento in Gomage feed pro

Tags: magento, gomage

We are using the module of Gomage to make a xml feed in Magento. Now we need to get the product id, but it will not work. We have tried product_id, but this does not give us the product id's. Does anyone know the attribute code for the product id (so not product_id)?

All other attributes are working fine.

Answer: instead of using product_id you have to use entity_id!

Comment: Show me your codes ..

Comment: I just placed my code, so at this moment you see product_id and that one is not working